# Hide collapse icon for collapsible panel in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

When I have a collapsible panel, ExtJs renders an icon in the tools area to expand/collapse, but also puts a little black triangle between the panels to do exactly the same thing.

I found in the documentation that I can hide the icon in the tools area, using hideCollapseTool:true, but I want to hide that little black triangle instead. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `split:false` on the panel?

Comment: This may be old but I had a similar issue. I tried setting `collapsible:false` and I was still seeing the icon. As soon as I put in `split:false`, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In Ext JS 5 (and likely some earlier versions as well) the `split` configuration parameter can be either a boolean value or a configuration object for an `Ext.resizer.BorderSplitter` object.

According to the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.resizer.BorderSplitter) the `collapsible` property can be used to manually show or hide the collapse button in the splitter, so you can set that property to `false` to hide that button you're talking about.

The solution tested and working in 5.1 looks like this, assuming the panel is contained in a container with a border layout:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    region: 'west',
    split: {
        collapsible: false
    }
}
```

P.S. I know this is 2 years late but I found this question while looking for the solution myself. Figured I might as well share the solution from the API.

Edit: [Made a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hhj). Also, it's worth mentioning that this retains all of the other splitter functionality that is lost if you use `split: false`, such as keeping the panel resizable.